# What is an alternative to Haystack for Django framework?

Tags: json, django, elasticsearch, nosql

### Brief description

With my team I'm creating a search engine for our project that contains a lot of data (I'm talking about millions). We use Django Framework & ElasticSearch because using a nosql search engine renders the results very fast.
We use Haystack because it provides an easy modular search system for Django.

### Search engine & data deeper explained

Our search engine contains two input fields. Both can be used but one is enough. Each item in our data has determined on which location it must be found. So, the user searches an item in one or multiple location and the search engine looks for each item out of a million and searches if that item has that location.

### Our problem & question

However, because we have **a lot** of data and our search engine will have a ranking method and deep filter system, we are hesitating if Haystack is the right system for us. We cannot add EVERY content of an item inside one .json.

Is there a better alternative that can handle more complex search results?

If we want to use a nosql search engine, but have complex data structure, how can we do that using elastic search? e.g.: using a sql based search engine we would look for all the connections inside tables.

Comment: There are bindings django to elastic, such as  https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl , using it together with DRF , works reasonably well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are lots of connections between items in your data, you should consider integrating a graph technology into your set up. Serialize your app's data unto the graph so you can fetch it later from the nodes rather than SQL tables.

The advantage you will get in using graph technology is that query performance stays constant even as your data grows.

You can consider working with GraphQL or ArangoDB.

These links might be helpful:

- https://arangodb.com
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggwH1x_gztY
- https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene
- https://www.techiediaries.com/django-graphql-tutorial/

Comment: Never heard of this GraphQL. I checked the ArangoDB and it does seem interesting. Thank you!